# Can I use @ConditionalOnExpression to check for an annotation's property value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-config, spring-boot-configuration

I want to have an annotation where it will pull in a different config class based on the value of property. It might work something like this:

(All of this is pseudo code)

The annotation:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Import(RedisConfig.class)
@Import(HazelCastConfig.class)
public @interface EnableCaching
{
    Class cacheType() default Redis.class;
}
```

An example of one of the configs:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnExpression;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;

import java.util.List;

@EnableCaching
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{T(com.mypackage.CacheAnnotationMatcher).checkCacheType(com.mypackage.Redis.class)}")
public class RedisConfig
{
    //...elided...
}
```

Where `CacheAnnotationMatcher.checkProperty` is a class and method I create that finds the `@EnableCaching` annotation and checks the `cacheType` property and returns true/false.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `@ConditionalOnExpression` here, I see absolutely no reason why your code wouldn't work, have your tried it?

Comment: It doesn't allow passing the class. It throws an error. And the "*" doesn't work for allowing all packages. Is there a way to pass a yaml property?

Comment: You could pass a Class like: `...checkCacheType(Class.forName('com.something.Clazz'))`. Or pass it as a String, and compare the String representation of the class. I'm not entirely sure, what do you mean by passing yaml property.

Comment: Yes, I will pass it as a string if I have to, but I'd prefer to pass it as a class.